# why Resource Controllers not working in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

route link

```
    <a href="{{ route('users.destroy', $user->id) }}">Delete</a>
```

define route

```
    Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

controller function

```
    public function destroy($id)
        {
            $delete = DB::table('users')->delete($id);
            if ($delete) {echo 'success';}
        }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with the actual problem? What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Can you please explain the actual problem? I mean post the error that you faced. Can you please post the output when you hit the user's routes?

Answer (score 0):

in the `delete` route, the method should be `delete`, you can write it in this way

```
<form action="{{ route('users.destroy', $user->id) }}" method="post">
   @csrf
   @method('delete')
   <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to find specific id then delete the same one

$user = User::findOrFail($id);

$user ->delete();